# Find sub-groups associate to a value and count consecutives sub-groups withing each ID

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I am asking your help to design a very efficient solution to rapidly go through a 14kk rows table.

Basically, the problem consists of finding for each ID the subgroups with Value==0 and count the number of consecutives subgroups (within each ID) with Value == 0 starting from him.

This new information needs to be saved in an external table composed of "ID", "subgroup" and "Count".

Trying to be as clear as possible, I will present an example.
Supposing we have the following database:

```
ID <- (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)   
subgroup <- c("1a1p", "1a2p", "1a3p", "2a1p", "2a2p", "2a3p", "2a4p", "2a5p", "2a6p", "3a1p", "3a2p", "3a3p", "3a4p", "3a5p")
Value <- c(2000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2000, 1800, 0, 0 , 0, 1750, 0)

df <- data.frame(ID, subgroup, Value)
```

For each `ID`, we need to find all the `subgroup` corresponding to a `Value == 0` and then `count` the number of consecutive IDs with Value == 0.
Therefore, the solution must look like:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 3)    
subgroup <- c("1a2p", "2a2p", "3a1p", "3a5p")
count <- c(1, 3, 2, 0)
solution_df <- data.frame(ID, subgroup, count)
```

Note that the `subgroup == "1a2p"` is present with a `count == 0` meaning that it is featured with `Value == 0` but there are 0 `subgroup` consecutive to him with the same `Value == 0`.

I really hope I was as clear as possible.

---

Performance measured using `system.info()` on the previous version of the problem where it was considering only features `subgroup` and `Value`:

`data.table` approach

```
user: 881.21  system: 109.73  elapsed: 993.43
```

`dplyr` approach

```
user: 91.66  system: 0.56  elapsed: 93.05
```

`base R` approach

```
user: 1.67 system: 0.29  elapsed: 2.06
```

---

#### Update

Performance on the updated task:

`dplyr` approach

```
user: 75.28  system: 1.00  elapsed: 77.16
```

`base R` approach

```
user: 104.75 system: 0.61  elapsed: 105.74
```

Comment: Your example throws errors

Comment: sorry I wrote it on my phone, now is fixed :)

Comment: It should be already fixed, isn't it? Thank you :P

Comment: Is the table sorted by ID? Or could the ID 1a1p re-appear in row 15, for eaxmple?

Comment: The database is sorted as I showed in the question.
The ID is a unique composite key. If you need more information, please be my guest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(grp = c(TRUE, diff(Value==0)>0)) %>% 
    filter(Value ==0) %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(grp)) %>%
    summarise(ID = first(ID), count = n()-1) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-grp) 
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#    ID count
#  <fctr> <dbl>
#1   1a2p     0
#2   2a2p     2
#3   3a1p     2
#4   3a5p     0
```

---

Or using `rle` from `base R`

```
data.frame(ID = with(df, ID[c(FALSE, diff(Value==0) > 0)]),
                 count = with(rle(df$Value==0), lengths[values]-1))
#     ID count
#1 1a2p     0
#2 2a2p     2
#3 3a1p     2
#4 3a5p     0
```

#### Update

With the updated question, we can do a group by

```
df %>% 
    mutate(grp = c(TRUE, diff(Value==0)>0)) %>%
    filter(Value == 0) %>%
    group_by(ID, grp = cumsum(grp)) %>%
    summarise(subgroup = first(subgroup), count = n()-1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#    ID subgroup count
#  <dbl>   <fctr> <dbl>
#1     1     1a2p     1
#2     2     2a1p     3
#3     3     3a1p     2
#4     3     3a5p     0
```

Or with `base R`

```
res <- setNames(stack(with(df, tapply(Value == 0, ID, FUN = 
   function(x) with(rle(x), lengths[values]-1))))[2:1], c("ID", "count"))
i1 <- with(rle(df$Value == 0), rep(seq_along(values)*values, lengths))

res$subgroup <- df$subgroup[!duplicated(cbind(df['ID'], i1)) & i1 > 0]
res
#   ID count subgroup
#1  1     1     1a2p
#2  2     3     2a1p
#3  3     2     3a1p
#4  3     0     3a5p
```

Comment: thank you! I am curious to do an efficiency test to discover which of these 3 approaches is faster

Comment: @Enrico You may use `microbenchmark` on a big dataset i.e. 1e6 or 1e7 and check which one is faster

Comment: With Data Table is not possible to use microbenchmark because it modify the input data, therefore, the result of 'system.info()' is user: 881.21    system: 109.73     elapsed: 993.43.
Your two approaches using microbenchmark are still running, I will update you later.

Comment: @Enrico Thanks, You can update in your post once it is done

Comment: I still have not been able to run it with microbenchmark because it would need to run a whole night for the base R solution and a whole night for the dplyr solution. Do you think that System.info() benchmark can be fine as well?

Comment: @Enrico Yeah, that would be good because you are assigning using `data.table`, then a single run with `system.time` will be sufficient

Comment: I just got an impressive result with you R base algorithm. 2.06 seconds to deal with 14kk records. However, I realized I did not properly presented the problem, therefore, I updated the question. How should I modify your algorithm to take into account that each subgroup belongs to an ID. This issue caused a subgroup to have 'count == 156' because it was considering subgroups belonging to the next ID.    
Then I can finally present the comparison between data.table, dplyr and rbase.

Comment: @Enrico Updated the post

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea using `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(Value == 0)][
           Value == 0, .(ID = first(ID), count = .N - 1), by = grp]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    grp   ID count
> 1:   2 1a2p     0
> 2:   4 2a2p     2
> 3:   6 3a1p     2
> 4:   8 3a5p     0
> ```

Comment: I realized I did not properly expose the problem, I added a minor change that caused a big issue. I am trying to figure out how to modify your code but it is not working. Can your algorithm be adapted to the updated problem or it needs a different approach?

Comment: I ll give it a look when I m back online.