# Count of consecutive zeros in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my dataframe. It has row names and column names.

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
   row1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   row2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  0
```

I would like to derive a column *test* based on consecutive zeros (from the last columns,  across the columns for each row. Below is an example. For the first row, there are 8 consecutive zeros, so the value in the *test* row should be 8. for the second row, the result should be 1 as only one zero. ( I want to consider from 15 and go back till where zeros are started).

```
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 test
   row1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8
   row2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the result for `c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`?

Comment: it supposed to be 2.

Comment: Can you explain why not 3?

Comment: hmm, thanks for pointing this out, I want to consider from the d5, d4 and go back. Basically since how many days the values are zeros.

Comment: @PoGibas I edited the question with example. let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find sub-groups associate to a value and count consecutives sub-groups withing each ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47548554/find-sub-groups-associate-to-a-value-and-count-consecutives-sub-groups-withing-e)  Try to check whether it can help or I will try to adapt the answer of @akrun to your question

Comment: deleted my answer as the example in the question keeps changing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using `rle`:

```
getConsecZeroRle <- function(x) {
    foo <- rle(x)
    foo$lengths[tail(which(foo$values), 1)]
}
result <- apply(df[, -1] == 0, 1, function(x) getConsecZeroRle(x))
df$test <- as.numeric(result)
df$test[is.na(df$test)] <- 0
```

Explanation:

Use `apply` to iterate over the subset of your dataframe. For each row calculate length of consecutive zeros (`rle`) and extract last value using `tail`. Rows that don't have zeros will produce `NA` (using `is.na(df$test)`) to replace them with zeros.

---

Solution using `sum`:

```
getConsecZeroSum <- function(x) {
    x[1:tail(which(!x), 1)] <- FALSE
    sum(x)
}
df$test <- apply(df[, -1] == 0, 1, function(x) getConsecZeroSum(x))
```

Explanation:

Extract last `FALSE` value in each row and turn everything to `FALSE` before it (`x[1:tail(which(!x), 1)] <- FALSE`) then use `sum` to count zero values from the end.

Result:

```
#      a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 test
# 1 row1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0    8
# 2 row2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  0    1
```

Comment: Here is my dataframe with only one row(it has some row names and colnames) 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 when I run through the code I get result integer(0) as output but I'm expecting 8.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply find the index of the first value that does not equal `0`(starting from the last column) and then subtract one:

```
df$test2 <- apply(df[,ncol(df):1]==0, 1, which.min) - 1

df
#  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 test2
#1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0     8
#2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1  1  0     1
```

---

Another answer:

Since I was curious about a way to do this without `apply`-ing over rows I came up with a (admittedly complicated) `Reduce` solution. Not a solution I recommend, but one I was interested to see if there was a way to do it:

```
iniCol <- setNames(df[,ncol(df)] == 0, as.numeric(df[,ncol(df)] == 0))
df$test2 <- Reduce(function(ini, add) {temp <- ifelse(pmin(as.numeric(names(ini)), add==0) == 0, ini, rowSums(cbind(ini, add == 0)))
                                       ini  <- setNames(temp, pmin(as.numeric(names(ini)), add==0))}, 
                   df[,(ncol(df)-1):1], 
                   ini = iniCol)
```

The idea behind this is to use the `names` attribute to track whether or not a column was ever `0`. If it was then we stop counting, otherwise continue counting.